# How can I record a macro across multiple files

Tags: macro, vscode

I have two code files open and I'm trying to write a macro for moving code from one file to the other. I start recording the macro in file A. After I enter all of the commands I need in file A, I switch into file B using `gt`. After I've switched, the commands that I run in file B are not included in the macro. If I try to end my recording with `q` while in file B, I instead initiate a new recording. When I go back to file A, my original macro is still recording. If I stop that recording and run the macro it only does the commands I entered in file A, but that does include the command to switch files.

If it helps, I'm using the vscodevim extension for vim emulation in Visual Studio Code

Is it possible for me to record commands across multiple files into a macro? If so, how?

Comment: It might be easier to write a function that runs `norm` commands than recording a macro.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem agreed, but im surprised that macro-recording doesn’t persist across tabs. Has OP tried with windows (splits) instead of tabs?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I tried using splits, but the macro recording is still confined to the window where I start it. From what I've read, it seems like the commands in different files stay separate from each other because they are tied to the buffer that they are run in, so switching buffers switches out of the macro recording. I think the suggestion from @DJMcMayhem to use a function with `norm` commands is the best way to do what I need.

Comment: @Rainbacon This must be a quirk of VSCode’s vim, because things work fine in terminal vim.

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been documented on the [VsCode/Vim](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) repo. Bugs [#5636](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/5636) and [#5123](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/5123) both show that this is a current limitation in this extension.

As stated in the above comments, recording and replaying macros across different buffers (whether they be splits or tabs) work just fine in vim itself.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se] and thanks for answering!